# Failed to download libimobiledevice.zip flutter Exception 404 Flutter

Tags: macos, flutter

Hello i updgraded my flutter version(1.17.4 to 2.0.0) and i was working in my proyect normally  and this issue showed up.  but i don't know how i can fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use a `sudo flutter doctor -v` or reinstall your flutter version.

**For MacOS** : https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=macos

Comment: Thanks i add the sudo in the command and it's works.

Comment: @JorgePerezMedina ok, no problem